# Trace (like OutputDebugString/Trace.writeline) from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've been looking for a while for a way to trace from SQL stored procedure on SQL Server.
I am talking about tracing to "DebugView", just like the function OutputDebugString() (or C#'s Trace.WriteLine()).

Does anyone know how to do that, or if it is even possible?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you executing these stored procedures? If from SSMS print statements are quickest and easiest if from your application you can use custom [SQL Profiler Events](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/16/Custom-user-configurable-SQL-Server-Profiler-events.aspx).

You could toggle logging off and off by altering the connection string.

```
IF APP_NAME() LIKE '%Debug%'
BEGIN
    DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(128), @user_data varbinary(8000)
    SELECT  @msg = N'A message', @user_data = cast('some data' as varbinary(8000))
    EXEC sp_trace_generateevent 82, @msg, @user_data
END
```

Comment: I tried your code and it doesn't seem to be calling `OutputDebugString`. Is the problem on my side, or is your answer intended as an alternative to `OutputDebugString`?